# What is the right way to register and unregister a listener in order to receive callbacks even when activity is not visible?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-lifecycle

I have a service helper singelton, which basically connects an Activity to a Service (sends requests and receives broadcasts and provides a callback interface for the Activity to implement)

The reccomended way is probably to do it onResume() / onPause() like this:

```
MyActivity extends Activity implements ServiceHelper.Callbacks {

   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       mServiceHelper.setListener(this);
   }

   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       // Avoid leaking this Activity
       mServiceHelper.setListener(null);
   }

}
```

This prevents the leaks, but in thas way the Activity might miss some important callbacks while paused / not visible. 
Ideally I would do it in onCreate() and onDestroy(), but [its stated](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) that the Activity is killable after onPause() so the Activity might get leaked (if I interpret this correctly)

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to receive/process anything in an activity when it is not active/visible?

Comment: I have a progress indicator in the activity which I want to set invisible when a background operation is finished

Comment: You can't check the operation progress status on `onResume()`?

Comment: You should provide more code. There is no one golden solution to this problem

Comment: @shoerat I haven't implemented that yet, but it sounds like a good option to check whether the progress is finished in onResume() thanks for the tip. But if azertiti is correct in his answer that might not be needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onCreate/onDestroy pair is the right one. If the application is getting killed by the system all memory is released so it's not possible to have leaks in that case.

Comment: If you can provide a link to a resource that makes it clear that if an Activity gets killed (before onDestroy() gets called) the whole application gets destroyed and relased from memory I would accept this as the correct answer

Comment: The "killing" does not happen at activity level, it is at process level. A detailed explanation can be found on this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want do some work when your app is active or paused take into account to use a Broadcast Receiver. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: I use BroadcastReceiver in the ServiceHelper singelton, but i want my activity to implement a more cleaner interface to handle callbacks